# Putting Huggingface model on GPU with torch.distributed

Tags: pytorch, distributed-computing, huggingface-transformers

I'm using Huggingface and I'm putting my model on GPU using the following code:

```
from transformers import GPTJForCausalLM
import torch
model = GPTJForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
                "EleutherAI/gpt-j-6B",
                revision="float16",
                torch_dtype=torch.float16,
                low_cpu_mem_usage=True,
                use_cache=False,
                gradient_checkpointing=True
)
model.to("cuda")
```

I would like to train on 2 GPUs using the following command fails:

```
python -m torch.distributed.launch --nproc_per_node 2 --nnodes=1 train.py
```

This causes an error because I think it tries to put both instances on the same GPU. When I remove the `model.to("cuda")` line it works fine (but it is then not running on GPU I guess).

How can I put the model on GPU when using multiple GPUs?

Comment: When moving to ddp you need to wrap it around a ddp class, and change your dataloader to distributed sampler. Plus u might want to look at something called global and local rank

Comment: If u find this too complicated, take a look at pytorch lightning they made a good wrapper for DDP, without too much code change but u need to understand how to use pl